# Property of Determinant over splitting into 2 determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I know this property well :
$$\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x & x^2 +a \\
    1 & y & y^2+b \\
    1 & z & z^2+c \\
    \end{vmatrix}
=
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x & x^2 \\
    1 & y & y^2 \\
    1 & z & z^2 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
+
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x & a \\
    1 & y & b \\
    1 & z & c \\
    \end{vmatrix}.
$$

But the question I am unable to find answer to is 
This applies to two rows or column at a time Like
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1+a & x+b & x^2+c \\
    1+d & y+e & y^2+f \\
    1+g & z+h & z^2+i \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

to simplify to
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x & x^2 \\
    1 & y & y^2 \\
    1 & z & z^2 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
            +       
    \begin{vmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    \end{vmatrix}.
$$

If it does to two even  rows please mention

Comment: This is not the case. This would imply that $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$, which is not always true. What you can do is iterate the linearity in each column; so you first split up the determinant using the first column, then split up each of those components using the second column, and so on.

Comment: You can write that as a sum of eight determinants, your two and six others.

Comment: @Dave It clears up : Its not general for every determinant and only  general for one row as mentioned first ,thus There is property for only one row not two rows simultaneously . So is the understanding uptill now right enough?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So the work is right($2^{nd}$)one  and comment by dave is wrong?

Comment: No, your version is incorrect. What he’s saying is that the determinant splits into the sum of the two terms that you’ve got plus another *six* terms.